# How to test a state machine using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, fsm

I am new to testing, and I need to find a way to test a state machine I wrote, similar to this https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577308-simple-state-machine-implementation/ using pytest.

The code takes a time series dictionary as input {timestamp: value}, then produces a new dictionary {timestamp: string}.

Here is an example of one of the functions that decide the state change:

```
def state_t_high():
    global current_element, duration_timer, recovery_timer, output_series
    # print("T_HIGH")
    if current_element == number_of_elements:
        return state_done
    elif input_series[inputList[current_element]] < THRESHOLD:
        current_element += 1
        return state_normal
    elif input_series[inputList[current_element]] >= THRESHOLD and duration_timer <= TRIGGER_DUR:
        duration_timer += 1
        current_element += 1
        return state_t_high
    elif input_series[inputList[current_element]] >= THRESHOLD and duration_timer > TRIGGER_DUR:
        duration_timer += 1
        output_series[inputList[current_element]] = 'too high'
        current_element += 1
        return state_p_high
```

As far as I can tell, the code is working fine, however I don't know how to actually test it properly. I haven't created any classes, the rest of the code is just downloading the input file and then uploading the result to a server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `global`s are the main problem. You need to encapsulate them in one way or another. E.g. as class members. I recommend to look at https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StateMachine.html

Answer (score 0):

Using global variables isn't good for testing. But, of course, you could always use [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and mock everything in the file. But it's an indicator that something not right with your code.

The problem of your function having too many side effects. It's always hard to test functions which not encapsulate data inside and change everything outside of their context.

I don't know the context of your app, but try to encapsulate global elements into a class. And try to follow TDD methodology. Start to write tests first defining interfaces.